# simple way to show my admob ad in every activity?

Tags: android, admob

I have a simple question: what is the easyest way to show my admob ad in every single activity in my app?

I dont want to load a new ad on every site, I just want to show the same ad on every page. What is the way to do this in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ViewStub`. `ViewStub` is used to place `AdMob` ads at Footer, you just have to create layout for this Footer and then include this layout in your XML layouts (activity layouts) by using ViewStub example.

Example:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity
{

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void setFooterAds()
    {
          // Make ViewStub visible
          // include your Ads code
    }
}
```

Comment: and how to implement the footer?